# A method generates the expected results in JUnit but it says it is null

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy, junit

I am starting in Unit test. I have a method and it is giving me the expected result, however, JUnit says it is generating null values. Basically, my method is generating even numbers. My code follows below:

My class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BasicCommandsReview {

    private ArrayList<Integer> listaDeNumeros = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> evenNumbersAsString = new ArrayList<>();

    void printEvenNumbers(int num) {
        for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
            if (i%2==0) {
                listaDeNumeros.add(i);
            }
        }

        int j=0;

        while(j < evenNumbersAsString.size() - 1){
            System.out.print(evenNumbersAsString.get(j) + ",");
            j++;
        }
        System.out.print(evenNumbersAsString.get(j));
    }

    void evenNumbersAsString(int num){

        int j=0;

        for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
            if (i%2==0) {
                evenNumbersAsString.add(i);
            }
        }
            while(j < evenNumbersAsString.size() - 1){
                System.out.print(evenNumbersAsString.get(j) + ",");
                j++;
            }
            System.out.print(evenNumbersAsString.get(j));
        }
}
```

My test class:

```
import org.junit.Test

class BasicCommandsReviewTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    BasicCommandsReview commandReview = new BasicCommandsReview()

    @Test
    void testEvenNumberAsString_Even() {
        assertEquals("Array par -OK", "2,4,6,8,10,12", commandReview.evenNumbersAsString(12))
    }

    @Test
    void testEvenNumberAsString_Odd() {
        assertEquals("Array impar -OK", "2,4,6,8,10,12,14", commandReview.evenNumbersAsString(15))
    }
}
```

The log i get when i run a test:

```
2,4,6,8,10,12
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Array par -OK 
Expected :2,4,6,8,10,12
Actual   :null


2,4,6,8,10,12,14
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Array impar -OK 
Expected :2,4,6,8,10,12,14
Actual   :null


    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:100)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1466)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.callStatic(StaticMetaClassSite.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)
    at BasicCommandsReviewTest.testEvenNumberAsString_Odd(BasicCommandsReviewTest.groovy:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Thanks in advance for all thoughts that may come

Comment: How does this even compile? You can't use a call to a `void` method as a method parameter.

Comment: Yes. It is Groovy

Comment: Not related to your question: Remove the @Test annotation. You're running JUnit 3 tests and therefore you should not add @Test to you methods. They are tests because the method name starts with `test`.

Comment: I changed and it keeps working. I didn't know it. Thanks Stefan

Comment: And dont forget about accepting answers at some point ;-)

Comment: I just did this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your methods aren't returning anything. They can't be: they have `void` return type:

```
void evenNumbersAsString(int num){
```

The only reason you can even invoke the method as a method parameter is because this is groovy. The equivalent in Java:

```
assertEquals("Array par -OK", "2,4,6,8,10,12", commandReview.evenNumbersAsString(12));
```

would be a compile-time error, because the 3rd parameter is of type `void`. I'm not familiar with groovy, but it looks like it's treating a `void` method as if it returns `Void` - which is non-instantiable, and so always `null`.

You're *printing* stuff, not returning it. If you want to check the result with `assertEquals`, you have to make your methods return a value, e.g. `String`.

Comment: I don't even know how i could let this kind of thing happen. I really didn't notice it. Thank you Andy.

Comment: @CaioVitor Note that if you're not *intending* to use Groovy dynamic typing, it's a good idea to use `@CompileStatic`, which would have caught this.

Comment: Ok, i will do it. Thank you

Comment: Sharp I spotting that groovy part !

Comment: @chrylis, when i add **@CompileStatic*, i get an error like this: Error:(11, 9) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Reference to method is ambiguous. Cannot choose between [void junit.framework.TestCase#assertEquals(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String), void groovy.util.GroovyTestCase#assertEquals(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)]
Error:(16, 9) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Reference to method is ambiguous. Cannot choose between [void junit.framework.TestCase#assertEquals(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String), void groovy.util.GroovyTest